# How to find the correct "word part" records that make up an input "word string", given a word part dataset?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, text, full-text-search

In [agglutinative languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutinative_language), "[words](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:884408/FULLTEXT01.pdf)" is a fuzzy concept. Some agglutinative languages are like Turkish, Inuktitut, and many Native American languages (amongst others). In them, "words" are often/usually composed of a "base", and multiple prefixes/suffixes. So you might have `ama-ebi-na-mo-kay-i-mang-na` (I just made that up), where `ebi` is the base, and the rest are affixes. Let's say this means "walking early in the morning when the birds start singing", `ama/early ebi/walk na/-ing mo/during kay/bird i/plural mang/sing na-ing`. These words can get quite long, like 30+ "letters".

So I was playing around with creating a "dictionary" for a language like this, but it's not realistic to write definitions or "dictionary entries" as your typical English "words", because there are a possibly infinite number of words! (All combinations of prefixes/bases/suffixes). So instead, I was trying to think maybe you could have just these "word parts" in the database (prefixes/suffixes/bases, which can't stand by themselves actually in the real spoken language, but are clearly distinct in terms of adding meaning). By having a database of word parts, you would then (in theory) query by passing as input a long say 20-character "word", and it would figure out how to break this word down into word parts because of the database (somehow).

That is, it would take `amaebinamokayimangna` as input, and know that it can be broken down into `ama-ebi-na-mo-kay-i-mang-na`, and then it simply queries the database for those parts to return whatever metadata is associated with those parts.

What would you need to do to accomplish this basically, at a high level? Assuming you had a database (SQL or just in a text file) containing these affixes and bases, how could you take the input and know that it breaks down into these parts organized in this way? Maybe it turns out there is are other parts in the DB which can be arrange like `a-ma-e-bina-mo-kay-im-ang-na`, which is spelled the the exact same way (if you remove the hyphens), so it would likely find that as a result too, and return it as another possible match.

The only way (naive way) I can think of solving this currently, is to break the input string into ngrams like this:

```
function getNgrams(str, { min = 1, max = 8 } = {}) {
  const ngrams = []
  const points = Array.from(str)
  const n = points.length
  let minSize = min
  while (minSize <= max) {
    for (let i = 0; i < (n - minSize + 1); i++) {
      const ngram = points.slice(i, i + minSize)
      ngrams.push(ngram.join(''))
    }
    minSize++
  }
  return ngrams
}
```

And it would then check the database if any of those ngrams exist, maybe passing in if this is a prefix (start of word), infix, or suffix (end of word) part. The database `parts` table would have `{ id, text, is_start, is_end }` sort of thing. But this would be horribly inefficient and probably wouldn't work. It seems really complex how you might go about solving this.

So wondering, how would you solve this? At a high level, what is the main vision you see of how you would tackle this, either in a SQL database or some other approach?

The goal is, save to some persisted area the word parts, and how they are combined (if they are a prefix/infix/suffix), and then take as input a string which could be *generated* from those parts, and try and figure out what the parts are from the persisted data, and then return those parts in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

First consider the simplified problem where we have a combination of prefixes only. To be able to split this into prefixes, we would do:

- Store all the prefixes in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).
- Let's say the input has n characters. Create an array of length n (of numbers, if you need just one possible split, or sets of numbers, if you need all possible splits). We will store in this array for each index, from which positions of the input string this index can be reached by adding a prefix from the dictionary.
- For each substring starting with the 1st character of the input, if it belongs to the Trie, mark the index as can be reached from 0th position (i.e. there is a path from 0th position to k-th position). Trie allows us to do this in O(n)
- For all i = 2..n, if the i-th character can be reached from the beginning, repeat the previous step for the substrings starting at i, mark their end position as "can be reached from (i-1)th position" as appropriate (i.e. there is a path from (i-1)th position to ((i-1)+k)th position).
- At the end, we can traverse these indices backwards, starting at the end of the array. Each time we jump to an index stored in the array, we are skipping a prefix in the dictionary. Each path from the last position to the first position gives us a possible split. Since we repeated the 4-th step only for positions that can be reached from the 0-th position, all paths are guaranteed to end up at the 0-th position.

Building the array takes O(n^2) time (assuming we have the trie built already). Traversing the array to find all possible splits is O(n*s), where s is the number of possible splits. In any case, we can say if there is a possible split as soon as we have built the array.

The problem with prefixes, suffixes and base words is a slight modification of the above:

- Build the "previous" indices for prefixes and "next" for suffixes (possibly starting from the end of the input and tracking the suffixes backwards).
- For each base word in the string (all of which we can also find efficiently -O(n^2)- using a trie) see if the starting position can be reached from the left using prefixes, and end position can be reached from right using suffixes. If yes, you have a split.

As you can see, the keywords are **trie** and **dynamic programming**. The problem of finding only a single split requires O(n^2) time after the tries are built. Tries can be built in O(m) time where m is the total length of added strings.